# Call Controller from kafka component

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, apache-kafka

I've been searching a lot about it, and the only two things I've found is that my design is possibly bad, but I doubt it is. The problem I am having is that I have Spring Kafka classes, where I have a trigger waiting for the messages that reach a topic, and when that info arrives I want to send it to my controller, and from my controller it will be taken to another microservice.

Could I autowired my controller without creating infinite instances?

[image: Name of classes: KafkaConsumer]

When kafka is activated I would like to call a method from my controller.

Code Kafka:

```
@Component
public class KafkaConsumer {

    private static final String TOPIC = "topic_name";


    @KafkaListener(topics = TOPIC)
    private void listen(String msg) {
        
      //Send msg to my controller
    }
}
```

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("controllerA")
public class Controller {

   private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

   @Autowired
   private MyService serviceA;

   // More services....

   private String sendMyMessageToAnotherMicroservice(String msg)
   {
     //Code...
     restTemplate.exchange("MyUrlInAnotherMicroservice:9090", HttpMethod.POST, msg,
                    String.class);
     //Code...
   }
   //More methods....

}
```

I need my kafka call my method 'sendMyMessageToAnotherMicroservice(String msg)'

Comment: What did you try? Is your controller a Spring bean?

Comment: Why don't you share the code needed by the controller and the kafka listener in a dedicated service ?

Comment: Yes is a spring bean @GreyFairer

Comment: your design is bad. the listener detach the message, and you can use service classes to process it. controller is for http request processing. in the service, you can send the message over http to the another microservice of course.

Comment: But I need the message I have received to be sent to the controller to send it to another microservice by means of a post request to insert it in a bbdd of that other microservice @ziaval

Comment: you should refactor the code and put the message sender into an individual service, then you can inject it into the listener and if you use it in the controller, then there too.

Comment: So if I want the kafka trigger to launch my controller method, I must necessarily put it in my controller @zlaval

Comment: i create an example as an answer, there i can show code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a separate service to the processor:

```
@Component
public class KafkaConsumer {

    @Autowired
    private MyKafkaProcessorService service;

    private static final String TOPIC = "topic_name";
    
    @KafkaListener(topics = TOPIC)
    private void listen(String msg) {          
      service.sendMyMessageToAnotherMicroservice(msg);
    }
}


@Service
public class MyKafkaProcessorService {

 //this can be a bean
   private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

   public String sendMyMessageToAnotherMicroservice(String msg){
         //Code...
      restTemplate.exchange("MyUrlInAnotherMicroservice:9090", HttpMethod.POST, msg,
                        String.class);
         //Code...
   }
}


@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("controllerA")
public class Controller {

   //if you need it in the controller then you can autowire there too
   @Autowired
   private MyKafkaProcessorService service;

   @Autowired
   private MyService serviceA;

   // More services....

  
   //More methods....

}
```